# Why did elixir change the notation for sending a message to a process?

Tags: elixir

I noticed that in elixir version 0.10.1, you send a message to a process like this

```
 my_process <- :message, self
```

But now in elixir 1.0.2, you send a message to a process like this

```
 Process.send my_process, :message, self
```

What was the reason for this change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to this change, list comprehensions looked like this:

```
lc x inlist my_list do
  # ...
end
```

However, the syntax was strange for newcomers and so the Elixir team set out to find an alternative. The winning syntax was

```
for x <- my_list do
  # ...
end
```

Now, the meaning of `<-` suddenly became dependent on the context. This is not generally a bad thing, but it is often harder to parse and may allow for ambiguities, so they decided to change it.

Another reason to use `send` instead of `<-` is to be consistent with the `receive` syntax. It makes much more sense to let these two have a similar visual appearance than handling them on different syntactic levels.

By the way, your usage of `Process.send/3` is wrong. [The third parameter must be `:noconnect` or `:nosuspend`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Process.html#send/3). Typically you would use the simpler and shorter [`send` (aka `Kernel.send`)](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#send/2) instead.

Comment: Using `send` will use the implementation from `Kernel.send(dest, msg)` which differs from `Process.send(dest, msg, options)`. Another cause for using `send` is the keyword `receive`. Using the symbol `<-` to send but the keyword `receive` to receive is somehow ambiguous.

Comment: @JuliusBeckmann thanks. Edited my answer to reflect the difference between `Kernel.send` and `Process.send`